# Php implementation for GMAIL API - filtering using multiple strings

Tags: php, google-api, gmail-api, google-api-php-client

For the GMAIL API - Is there a way to use multiple strings in the query without looping through each string individually.  Below are some use cases:

1 - Get all results for emails that contain either domain1.com or domain2.com

```
$list = $service->users_messages->listUsersMessages('me',
  ['maxResults' => 100, 'q' => 'domain1.com  domain2.com']);
```

2 - Get all results for emails that contain either domain1.com or domain2.com and each domain specifically matches a string

```
$list = $service->users_messages->listUsersMessages('me',
  ['maxResults' => 100, 
   'q' => 'domain1.com statement ready, domain2.com view your statement']);
```

3 - Get all results for emails that specifically matches a string

```
$list = $service->users_messages->listUsersMessages('me',
  ['maxResults' => 100, 
   'q' => 'statement ready, view your statement']);
```

The comma in all the scenarios above is the separator of the string.  The query works fine if i have a single domain or string.  But it fails to return any result that have both of the strings in it e.g statement ready and view your statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the query as "AND" and "OR". If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? As a sample string, here, it uses "sample1", "sample2" and "sample3".

#### Pattern 1 :

If you want to retrieve mails including all strings of "sample1", "sample2" and "sample3", you can use the following query. It uses the space.

```
sample1 sample2 sample3
```

Also you can use like this. When the strings is enclosed by the parentheses, the strings in the the parentheses are used as "AND".

```
(sample1 sample2 sample3)
```

#### Pattern 2 :

If you want to retrieve mails including at least one of strings of "sample1", "sample2" and "sample3", you can use the following query. `OR` is uppercase letter.

```
sample1 OR sample2 OR sample3
```

Also you can use like this. When the strings is enclosed by the curly bracket, the strings in the curly bracket are used as "OR".

```
{sample1 sample2 sample3}
```

#### Pattern 3 :

From pattern 1 and 2, if you want to retrieve mails including both "sample1" and "sample2" OR mails including "sample3", you can use the following query.

```
{(sample1 sample2) sample3}
```

#### Reference :

- [Search operators you can use with Gmail](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en)

Comment: These operators for the Gmail web interface not the GMAIL API.  I have attempted similar combinations but it didn't work.  Thanks for trying though.

Comment: @user9465677 If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry. I'm sorry for the inconvenience. In my environment, for example, I can use ``{(sample1 sample2) sample3}`` and ``sample1 OR sample2`` at ``q`` of 
 ``gmail.users.messages.list``.

Comment: let me play around with it.  May be I am doing something wrong.

Comment: @user9465677 If it didn't work, when you provide the sample query, I would like to confirm it in my environment. You can also test at https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list

Comment: Pattern 1 and 2 I was able to make them work with some by putting all the AND statements in the parenthesis and then OR outside.   I didn't have a use case for Pattern 3.  The learning for me is the strings don't just mix and match you have to be very specific about them.

Comment: @user9465677 Thank you for your additional information. When you use pattern3, how about doing URL encode?